# should yarn.lock and .yarnclean file follow git versioning?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have integrated yarn manager in my node.js application. Now Through yarn **yarn.lock** and **.yarnclean** files are generated. Should I put them in .gitignore or should they follow git versioning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**.yarnclean** You can put into **.gitignore** file

**You should add yarn.lock to your git, don't ignore it.**

When you run either yarn or yarn add , Yarn will generate a **yarn.lock** file within the root directory of your package. You don’t need to read or understand this file - just check it into source control. When other people start using Yarn instead of npm, the yarn.lock file will ensure that they get precisely the same dependencies as you have.

Comment: The stuff about `.yarnclean` is wrong.  `.yarnclean` should be in verion control, see: https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/autoclean/  *"The .yarnclean file should be added to version control."*

Answer (score 5):

Both files should be part of your version control.

`.yarnclean` is generated by running the `yarn clean` command. From [the docs](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/clean/#toc-yarn-clean):

> Yarn will create a `.yarnclean` file that should be added to version control.

`yarn.lock` is used to get consistent installs of dependencies across machines — it contains extra information that `package.json` does not which allows `yarn` to do this (one of the main advantages over `npm` and something that other projects like [`npm-shrinkwrap`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/shrinkwrap) have tried to address.

As [the `yarn` docs say](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/yarn-lock#toc-check-into-source-control),

> All yarn.lock files should be checked into source control (e.g. git or mercurial)